# How to install Mail.php with Pear and XAMPP?

Tags: php, xampp, pear

I'm really struggling to get a local build of a php website running. The code is quite messy, and very dated. It is being upgraded from PHP5 to PHP8.
I'm running Windows, and trying to get the code working using XAMPP.
However, when I run the server I get an issue saying that Mail.php failed to open for inclusion. I checked Pear under the XAMPP folders and Mail doesn't seem to be there.
I tried to use the XAMPP shell to install Mail, but this gives me an error saying -

> PHP Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly
> braces is no longer supported in...

I'm not sure what to do here to get a build up and running, I'm new to PHP and have very little support. Can someone please give me a simple explanation on what I want to upgrade/do to get the code running on Windows?

Thanks

Comment: `PHP Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported`...this indicates that whatever code you're running uses syntax which isn't supported in PHP8. The fix for that is to go and update the code. In that specific case, it's generally as simple as changing `{` and `}` for `[` and `]` on the lines mentioned by the error (e.g. something like `$arr{"ID"}` would need to become `$arr["ID"]`). I'm sure you can learn more about this error if you google it! Of course that doesn't mean there won't be other subsequent issues - PHP5 to 8 is a big jump in one go

Comment: Whatever this old Mail library is you're trying to install though, likely there's either a more modern version, or if it's been discontinued / abandoned by its maintainer, your options are a) try to fix it yourself (as per my comment above) or b) use a different library which provides similar functionality. Assuming it's used for sending emails, you could try something like PHPMailer instead.

Comment: Or are you saying that the _installer_ program is the one which threw that error? It wasn't 100% clear. If so, you'd firstly need to tell us precisely what command you ran in the shell to try and install this package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using XAMPP, and the project makes use of Pear Mail. But this is not in my XAMPP files.
So in XAMPP I opened the shell, and did ```pear install -a Mail```. This is when I got the error.

Comment: Ok. What version of the Pear installer have you got? Maybe _that_ is what is out of date and doesn't run on PHP8.

Comment: Frustratingly, even running ```pear version``` from the XAMPP shell errors. But looking at the XAMPP readme it says I have PHP 8.2.12 (VS16 X86 64bit thread safe) + PEAR

Comment: Seems you're not the only person with this issue - see the duplicate

Comment: What duplicate? I don't see anything

Comment: If it's not showing, refresh the page